# Make up a new continuous variable from other two

Tags: data-transformation, continuous-data, valuation

Suppose you are analyzing gambling addiction behavior (I changed the actual subject to make it more understandable) and that you consider the following interpretation:

- A really good player is one that always gambles, and always wins
- A good-medium player is one that rarely gambles, but always wins
- A bad-medium player is one that rarely gambles, but always loses
- A really bad player is one that always gambles, and always loses

If, somehow, I can measure that behaviour as two continuous variables:

- A: how often a person plays
- B: how often a person loses when playing

I am trying to make up a new variable that contains both A and B so I can measure that "badness of a player" (calling it BP), but I haven't been able to come up with a good mathematical solution.

For instance, I measured both A and B from 4 different players:

```
player        A     B
good         0.9   0.1
medium-good  0.1   0.1
medium-bad   0.1   0.9
bad          0.9   0.9
```

Doing `BP = A*B²`, I get:

```
player        A     B   BP
good         0.9   0.1  0.009
medium-good  0.1   0.1  0.001
medium-bad   0.1   0.9  0.081
bad          0.9   0.9  0.729
```

Which partially solves my problem, since I've been able to identify, without any doubt, the really bad players. However, I haven't been able to identify the really good ones, since their BP value is not the smaller one.

Note that a simple `A*B` would put the good and medium-bad player in the same level.

And, if `BP = A/B` the medium-good and the really-bad players are in the same level)

Is there another transformation or mathematical formula I could use to get a good measure of BP, ie, that follows the order from good to bad player?

PS: I'm not sure if this is the appropriate exchange site to post this on or if I should go to math.stackexchange, please let me know.

PS2: I also couldn't find a proper title, please let me know if you have a suggestion or feel free to edit it

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert in gambling, but your classification seems a bit strange to me. Why do you care about whether a player gambles always or rarely, as long as that person always wins. In other words, the first variable doesn't really have impact in your scheme and, thus, can (should) be eliminated. Perhaps, there are more sophisticated schemes, for example, based on games theory, which represent a multivariate model. Your model easily can be transformed into one, if you assume that desire (or habit) to gamble has significant impact on the player's performance (result).

Comment: I changed the actual subject to make it more understandable to any audience. I'm actually working with some financial ratios and we see that behaviour in some investment-related ratios . Some companies invest in a type X of assets, which is good only if their result with those assets is also good. If they invest a lot of money and have a bad return, it's the worst case possible. On the other hand, even if their return is awful but that doesn't represent much of their total investments...well, it's not that bad, but it's still worse than a company that invests very little but with good results

Comment: Why do you want to make a new continuous variable when effect of 2 variables can easily be analyzed using different statistical techniques? Alternatively, you can analyze ordered factor variable (good, medium-good, medium-bad, bad) with techniques similar to continuous.

Comment: Try changing the location of B so that its positive for good players and negative for bad. Then when you multiply it by A, very good = high positive, med-good = low positive, med-bad = low negative, very-bad = high negative.